# Failed to Execute if Block Statements just because of Condition Checking is always false in Android using JAVA?

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

can someone please help me what wrong with below written "IF CODE" this is not coming inside block everytime even the values before if is logged in console.

```
 if(userNameString == userInstance.getUsername() && passwordString == userInstance.getPassword())
```

Here is the complete code:

```
if(userInstance == null)
    {
        Log.i("no record found againse User Instance",""+userInstance); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "User Id and Password is wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(arg0.getId());
    
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Record found againse User Instance 1st",""+userInstance + "userName:" + userNameString +":pass:::"+passwordString);  
        if(userNameString == userInstance.getUsername() && passwordString == userInstance.getPassword())
        {
            Log.i("Record found againse User Instance 2nd",""+userInstance);    
            //Log.i("UserInstance else","" + userInstance);
            SessionManager.saveLoginCredentials(context,userInstance.getUsername().toString(),userInstance.getPassword().toString());
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivityService.this,
                    ProposalListActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            
            getLoaderManager().destroyLoader(arg0.getId());
        }
        
    }
```

**Here is the LogCat:**

> 02-04 22:36:39.150: I/on LoadFinished of Loader(14572): Name: kong,Password: f10343d1dc8d44c8935b356aa3f8aae2,First Name: Kong
>
> 02-04 22:36:39.150: I/Record found againse User Instance 1st(14572): Name: kong,Password: f10343d1dc8d44c8935b356aa3f8aae2,First Name: KonguserName:kong:pass:::kongkong

***EDIT:**
There was some logical problem the password i was getting from webservice is encoded instead of text and i was comparing the text with encoded value thats why the block of if statements were not executed.**

Comment: I thought this is the first day I won't see this question :_( I was wrong. As always.

Comment: This is too many times answered that use equals to compare Strings..

Comment: Based on the logcat output, it looks like your password is wrong. Just compare "kongkong" with "f10343d1dc8d44c8935b356aa3f8aae2"

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier  yes i was getting password from service in encoded form while user is entering in text thats why i am getting error now it is fine thanks to debug u r better than others who is just saying its duplicate question or use .equals  i have used .equal  but its logical prblem can u pls upvote

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier  can u help me how to convert encoded string into real string/text

Comment: You should do more research and maybe post a new question.... BUT the basic idea is 1) get the password in text, 2) encode it, 3) compare the encoded versions.

Comment: Good luck, and if I were you, I would delete this question....

Answer (score 2):

In String you must use [`String#equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) method for checking instead of `==`.

Use following code:

```
if(userNameString.equals(userInstance.getUsername()) && 
      passwordString.equals(userInstance.getPassword()))
```

Comment: have alreaduy used that but still no reponse

Comment: @user3233280 Now you have another problem. Debug your code.

Comment: tnx @ᴍarounᴍaroun for your great edit

Comment: please be more clear @user3233280 that we can help you, tell use what is the real problem and post relevant code

Comment: @Richard Le mesurier   have debug my code and that was the actual problem

Comment: can someone pls upvote my question ?

Comment: edit done please see it

Comment: see comment on your main question, you need use encode too on android side for your password

Answer (score 1):

use `equals` method instead of `==` to compare strings

```
 if(userNameString.equals(userInstance.getUsername()) && passwordString.equals(userInstance.getPassword()))
```